# Is this Bad Capacitor repairable on this power supply?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, damage

A capacitor blew on my B-Tron 16-8-1 power supply.

When I removed the cover and unseated and reseated the fuse. The power supply began to function again. BUT the power it was giving to each channel 13.4 to 13.44 volts DC.

I finally noticed a huge amount of tan colored build up between 5 Capxon 1000uf capacitors. And there is clearly a hole on the top of  of these capacitors.

[Hi-Res images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQ83.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to repair this board? If so.. Is this board worth repairing? Why is it functioning if this capacitor blew? Is this unit functioning properly if each channel is giving me 13.4+ volts?

Please check out the hi-res images link above. Thanks.

Comment: That yellowish buildup is likely just a glue to hold capacitors and coil firmly in place to reduce noise. It's totally possible to replace those capacitors but they are likely result, not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That tan colored buildup is a 'hot glue' and for hotter temps than regular hot glue. You can also see the glue holding down the inductor.

Usually capacitors will exhibit corrosion or a bulge when defective, it usually comes out from the top or bottom on electrolytic capacitors. The capacitors look fine from the pics shown above. Here is what a bad cap looks like:

[image]
Source: https://www.robotroom.com/Faulty-Capacitors-1.html

Sometimes they also look like a firecracker (literally) if they have exploded.

If you really think the capacitors are bad get an [ESR meter](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&channel=cus&q=capactor%20ESR%20meter), and desolder the capacitors and measure the ESR for those capacitors. I would estimate that the ESR for a cap that size should be below 1Ω

If the supply isn't at the right DC voltage, it's probably a feedback problem with the controller. If the supply has too much AC ripple, then its more likely that you have a bad capacitor.

Comment: What do you think about the 13.44 volts i'm getting from each channel? Because this unit was not function before I re-seated the fuse.

Comment: How do I know your unit is not functioning? I don't know the voltage that your PS is supposed to supply.

Comment: it was on a site and nothing was getting any power from it. I did replace the unit with a new one. And everything started working just fine. When I brought the unit home. The first thing I attempted to do was reseat the power supply fuse. After doing so, the unit turned on just fine, And the channels were outputting a voltage. On a brand new unit each channel outputs 11.9 to 12 volts exactly. After installing fuses on all channels on the channel boards. I'm getting 13.3 volts on each channel.

Answer (score 4):

The stuff you see around the capacitors is an epoxy potting compound to keep them from making noise while the PSU is operating (it’s on the filter toroid too, for the same reason.)

When big electrolytics fail, they vent out the top. There is an ‘X’ scored in the top to allow them to vent if that happens. This would be super-obvious (and smelly) if that happened. You will see a bulge at the top. I didn’t see evidence of this in the photos.

A too-high voltage may be indicating another problem however, that something is fishy in the regulation loop. Try testing the PSU with a dummy load like a resistor or an incandescent bulb. If possible, compare it with a known good one, load and no-load.

That said, if I were dealing with this in the field and I have a bunch of expensive stuff attached to it I’d be more inclined to just swap the supply.

Comment: _"... epoxy potting compound to keep them from making noise ..."_ - The purpose of the epoxy is to fix them to the board, so vibrations and shocks don't cause the component leads to flex. Without this additional support, components (such as inductors, electrolytic caps, and TO-220 parts) experiencing enough vibrations or shocks can eventually break their leads. It's not usually intended for noise reduction; electrolytics don't usually make sound, and inductors in a poorly designed PSU can easily still make noise with the amount of epoxy shown (I've had a motherboard where that was the case).